# Android Google Drive SDK upload files?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

It is possible to upload file though Google Drive SDK?
I've imported google play services as library and I can create only an empty file or a folder.

```
Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
  .createFolder(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet)
  .setResultCallback(
  new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(
    DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult result) {
    if (!result.getStatus()
    .isSuccess()) {
    show("Error while trying to create the folder");
    return;
    }
  Log.d("info","Folder created");
}
```

But how I can upload a file or multiple to Google Drive programatically?

Comment: I'm not taking my time to answer it, but be aware that the upload will be done by Google Play Services asynchronously to your app. If you want more control, use Googe Api Java Client Drive service.

Answer (score 0):

I've only used drive-sdk with python, so I don't know the details of uploading files using android. Anyway, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#examples) provides a toturial in Java that shows you how to upload a file to Drive. It might help you with your request.

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'Drive API for Android', you need to either:

1) newDriveContents(), THEN write to the DriveContents that you receive, THEN createFile() using that DriveContents.

2) createFile(), THEN get that file's DriveContents, THEN write to the DriveContents, then commit() the changes to that DriveContents.